# Could the limit be obtained by a Riemann sum?

Tags: limits, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

For $0<s<1$ and $n=1,2,\dots$, let $\Delta_n=1/(2n)$, $x_k=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{2n}$ and
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\Delta_n}{x_k}e^{\frac{-s\Delta_n}{x_k}}.
$$
Then, could we think of $a_n$ as a Riemann sum so as to obtain that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{-s}{x}}dx?
$$
However, it seems strange when dealing with the exponent in $a_n$. It is possible to derive the limit (as an integral) in this way? Please give me some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean $\Delta_k=1/(2k)$?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I think the Riemann sum corresponding to that integral would have exponent $-\frac{s}{x_k}$, not $-\frac{s\Delta_n}{x_k}$.

Comment: I think so. But, it does have $\Delta_n$. Annoying...